# Creating English Dictionary Desktop Application

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a dictionary API to use in my windows application. Is there any such API available, which I can add as a reference in my application, or are there any better solutions?

Comment: Do you mean a dictonary (as in looking up the definition of a word) or a spell-checker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a list of english words (without definitions), try something like [ASpell](http://aspell.net/).

You can then load it into a HashSet in C#

Answer (score 1):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/) have an API that you can use :

- [Dictionary Developers API Centre](http://developer.dictionary.com/)

The API is also free for non-commercial use.